# JAWS does not announce aria-describedby on select box in IE

Tags: html

I am trying to use aria-describedby on select box, but JAWS does not announce the text associated using the aria-describedby attribute in IE. I have even added tabindex="-1" to the span tag which is being referenced.Below is the sample code I am using. Can somebody please provide me any information on this topic.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="State">State</label> 
    <select  id="State" name="State" aria-describedby="spanId">
      <option value="acct">Choose</option>
      <option value="act">ACT</option>
      <option value="nsw">NSW</option>
      <option value="nt">NT</option>
      <option value="qld">QLD</option>
      <option value="sa">SA</option>
      <option value="tas">TAS</option>
      <option value="vic">VIC</option>
      <option value="wa">WA</option>
      </select>
      <span id="spanId" tabindex="-1">This is the text</span>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: What version of JAWS are you using? You need to have version 12 or later. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704594/how-to-get-jaws-to-read-aria-describedby-attribute

Comment: The version of JAWS that I am using is 14.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aria-label="spanId"`

Make sure you don't use `title` and `aria-label`for the same HTML element because title gets suppressed.

Comment: Unless the code snippet was altered I don't follow how `title` is relevant here.

Comment: @vpiTriumph, It is just additional info to the OP, because aria-label suppresses everything else. I see code usually with title as well. Just a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Using IE11 and Jaws 17 I have observed this issue as well.

My take is that this is a bug.

Until it's addressed by Freedom Scientific, I'd recommend using `aria-labelledby`.

This means something slightly different semantically:

> a label describes the essence of an object, while a description
>   provides more information that the user might need.

Source: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute)

But it's probably the best substitute you have available.